# Converting periodic panel data to country/day time sequence using Stata/purr/pandas

Tags: r, pandas, time-series, stata

| id | country | start_date | end_date | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx1 | xx | 01/12/2020 | 25/12/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| yy1 | yy | 03/12/2020 | 25/12/2020 | 2 | 3 |
| xx2 | xx | 27/12/2020 | 10/03/2022 | 4 | 2 |

I need to convert a periodic dataset (N 400) formatted like this into country/day while maintaining the var1 and var2 observations across each day within the periods.

I need a new approach since using loops and `tsfill` in Stata to replace dates doesn't work, i.e. the code runs but the data is still missing information in all rows between periods since neither `id` nor `country` is present in the imputed dates. Similarly, I've tried the following method in purr package in R:

```
res1 <- melt(setNames(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) seq(df[x, "start_date"],
                                                           df[x, "end_date"], by = "1 day")), df$country))
```

In the end, it should look like this:

| id | country | date | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx1 | xx | 01/12/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| xx1 | xx | 02/12/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| xx1 | xx | 03/12/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| yy1 | yy | 03/12/2020 | 2 | 3 |

....

| id | country | date | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx1 | xx | 25/12/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| yy1 | yy | 25/12/2020 | 2 | 3 |
| xx1 | xx | 26/12/2020 | . | . |
| yy1 | yy | 26/12/2020 | . | . |
| xx2 | xx | 27/12/2020 | 4 | 2 |
| yy1 | yy | 27/12/2020 | . | : |

I'm not familiar enough with pandas, however I was told that this may be the best way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as *the way* or *the best way* to do this. It should be quite easy in any environment for data management worth discussion.

For a Stata solution, note that the example is ambiguous over whether your date variables are string or already properly formatted numeric date variables. This assumes the first, but the calls to `daily()` should be omitted otherwise.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str3 id str2 country str10(start_date end_date) byte(var1 var2)
"xx1" "xx" "01/12/2020" "25/12/2020" 1 4
"yy1" "yy" "03/12/2020" "25/12/2020" 2 3
"xx2" "xx" "27/12/2020" "10/03/2022" 4 2
end

gen s_date = daily(start_date, "DMY")
gen e_date = daily(end_date, "DMY")
gen duration = e_date - s_date + 1 
expand duration 
bysort id country: gen date = s_date + _n - 1 
format %tdDD/NN/CCYY date 

list id country start end date var1 var2 in 1/10

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |  id   country   start_date     end_date         date   var1   var2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   01/12/2020      1      4 |
  2. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   02/12/2020      1      4 |
  3. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   03/12/2020      1      4 |
  4. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   04/12/2020      1      4 |
  5. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   05/12/2020      1      4 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   06/12/2020      1      4 |
  7. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   07/12/2020      1      4 |
  8. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   08/12/2020      1      4 |
  9. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   09/12/2020      1      4 |
 10. | xx1        xx   01/12/2020   25/12/2020   10/12/2020      1      4 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

An R approach using `dplyr::group_split` to split by `id` and `tidyr::complete` to add obs. for all days may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  dplyr::group_split(id) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(function(x) { 
    mutate(x, date = NA) %>% 
           tidyr::complete(date = seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = "day"), id = id, country = country, var1 = var1, var2 = var2) %>%
      select(-start_date, -end_date)
    })
#> # A tibble: 490 × 5
#>    date       id    country  var1  var2
#>    <date>     <chr> <chr>   <int> <int>
#>  1 2020-12-01 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  2 2020-12-02 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  3 2020-12-03 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  4 2020-12-04 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  5 2020-12-05 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  6 2020-12-06 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  7 2020-12-07 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  8 2020-12-08 xx1   xx          1     4
#>  9 2020-12-09 xx1   xx          1     4
#> 10 2020-12-10 xx1   xx          1     4
#> # … with 480 more rows
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c("xx1", "yy1", "xx2"),
           country = c("xx", "yy", "xx"),
        start_date = c("01/12/2020", "03/12/2020", "27/12/2020"),
          end_date = c("25/12/2020", "25/12/2020", "10/03/2022"),
              var1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L),
              var2 = c(4L, 3L, 2L)
)
```